# Filter to move email to the "sent folder"

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is it possible to create a Gmail filter to redirect incoming email (those sent by me to me) to the "sent" folder?

I use a VBA script to send email from Excel through `smtp.googlemail.com`. Unfortunately, this method doesn't allow a copy of email to be stored in the sent folder. My workaround, I think, is to send a bcc copy of the email to myself and create a Gmail filter to move the email to the sent folder. This seems easy enough until I realized that I didn't know how to create a filter to do so. In the "choose label..." drop down box, there is no option for "sent folder".

Any help?

Comment: TBH I think I would just settle on creating another label (eg. `SentViaScript`) for these emails and set up the appropriate filter in gmail (skip inbox etc.). Since they weren't really sent via gmail it could be misleading to try and fake this (if that is even possible), and with their own label they are more easily identifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail mailbox doesn't use the "folder" concept. Instead it use views, labels and categories.

All the messages that have in the from: field the mailbox email address, will be in the Sent view.

Comment: Not true. You can, for example, delete emails from Sent. You can then undelete them, which you do by sending them to the inbox. Sometimes they go to sent, but sometimes they go to inbox. I haven't figured out the details. I just went through it because I accidentally deleted everything and had to restore it. Almost nothing from me went to sent. It went to inbox.

Comment: Just wait for Gmail to index the restored messages.

Comment: Hmmm. How long will that take? I guess I'll check back in a day or two. P.S. I'm impressed with how fast you replied to a post to a 5 and a half year old thread. :)

Comment: Still in inbox and not in sent (most of them).

Comment: If you are looking for help, I suggest you to post a new question.

Comment: Not looking for help. Just adding to the data, which was apparently incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Outlook.

Here's how:

1. Migrate everything to Gmail.
2. Install Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook.
3. Let it sync with Gmail (may take a long time if you have a lot of mail).
4. Move the old "sent" emails into Gmail's "sent" folder (label) with Outlook.